# Returning to the UK for Holidays after a previous visit

Tags: visas, uk, us-citizens

I am a US citizen with a boyfriend in the UK. My "leave to enter" visa expired on October 31, 2015 (I left on Oct 15). I want to go back to the UK for the holidays but I want to know that they will let me back in for 2 weeks. I will have a return flight home, I just cant find ANYTHING that states if I have to wait a certain amount of time to return or if I am all good.

I want to book my flight asap but want to make 100% sure they will let me in!

Comment: There is no cooling-off period for visitor visas, or in your case, LTE.  You can come and go as often as you want BUT you need to clear the landing interview each and every time. There are lots of places on this site where the rule is explained that there's no cooling-off period.  Are you OK with that or would you like a 'formal answer'?

Comment: Does that mean that you have just spent 5½ months in the UK?

Comment: @JonathanReez This is not a duplicate, as the OP has not overstayed.

Comment: @GayotFow it could be nice to have a canonical answer for these kinds of questions on http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23438/can-i-leave-the-uk-and-come-back-in-on-a-tourist-visa