# 2 month valid visa left, any problem to return UK?

Tags: visas

I am planning to go to China for business trip with my boss on 12/12/2015 and back on 19/12/2015, the day might be changed but should be 7 days and before Christmas. I just checked my visa is Tier 5 youth mobility visa and will expire on 5/3/2016, I hear people mention if I return to UK later, I need to have 3 month or 6 month valid visa. Because I have been rejected to enter the UK before (but I was under a special case and accident, so UKGOV accept my reason and approve my visa application after that) so I am worried about any problem for me to return UK after that. Does anyone know the policy and can support a link on gov website that mentions similar requirement or mention my case is alright to return?

Comment: What is your citizenship? UK?

Comment: I am holding British national oversea passboard , thanks

Comment: What is a passboard ??

Comment: There isn't a link that says a visa runs until its expiry date.  It's implicit within the broader context of visas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I leave the UK and come back in, on a Tourist visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23438/can-i-leave-the-uk-and-come-back-in-on-a-tourist-visa)

Comment: @JonathanReez It's not a duplicate as the tier 5 youth mobility visa isn't a normal tourist visa.

Comment: @JonathanReez the OP seems concerned about a minimum remaining validity of his visa, not sure it's a dupe

Answer (score 1):

According the the [Tier 5 (Youth Mobility Scheme) page](https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-youth-mobility/overview):

> **How long you can stay**
>
> You’ll be given a visa to live and work in the UK for up to 24 months.
>
> You can enter the UK at any time while your visa is valid, and leave and come back at any time during your stay.
>
> > If you turn 31 while you’re in the UK, you can stay for as long as your visa is valid.