# Stay in UK for Canadian passport holders

Tags: canadian-citizens

I am a British citizen and i live in UK with my family. My mother is a Canadian citizen and is visiting me now.
She visited me last year from sept 2015 to Feb 2016. And this time she came to us again (entered UK on 28 May 2016). 
On her passport the immigration people stamped 6 months entry on both the occasions.

Q1-I needed to know that if she is planning to leave UK mid July this year, how soon will it be that she can re enter to visit me?

Q2- is this really true that in a year she can only stay in UK FOR 6 months in total?

Q3- if she wishes to come and see me again after leaving in JULY this year, can she do it in Sept this year, and will she be allowed again a new 6 months entry from that point?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I leave the UK and come back in, on a Tourist visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23438/can-i-leave-the-uk-and-come-back-in-on-a-tourist-visa)

Comment: Your mother could stay longer than six months if she can get [the appropriate visa](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/family-visas).  I've voted to close as "too broad" because Q2 is really a different question (which belongs on http://expatriates.stackexchange.com).